# robot framework installation on ubuntu selenium2library cannot

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

Hi i tried to install Rf on ubuntu(VM box) like here:
http://testingknols.blogspot.com/2014/05/robot-framework-installation-on-ubuntu.html
but problem is with selenium2library.
when I am using "S python" i got the message in termina "command not found"

when I am using:
import Selenium2Library I can see:
he program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install 
what should I do?
My python version is 2.7.6

Comment: What is "S python"? Can you please show _exactly_ how you are trying to run a test, and the _exact_ error message?

Comment: *"when I am using: import Selenium2Library I can see: he program 'import' can be found in the following packages: * imagemagick *"* Because you're not in Python; that's shell/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is "S python".
I just installed the selenium2library. You can install it using the console with:

```
$ pip install robotframework-selenium2library
```

Then you can use this library in your .robot file importing it, writing inside the setting block of the test:

```
Library     Selenium2Library
```